# How to detect method replacements done by the Eclipse Debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, deployment

I am looking for a way to detect inside a debugged application that a class file was modified by Eclipse.

The reason I am looking is to check if that class is used during the initialisation of the application and execute it again. So that life modifications work for these types of classes, too.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of application, web app? standalone?

If it's a webapp, do you use WTP or an application server outside eclipse ?

Anyway, if eclipse doesn't see all your modifications, you can take a look at Jrebel :
http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/

Comment: I am looking for the other way round: Eclipse is able to notice the changes and do the code replacement. But I want the **application** to be able to notice which classes have been replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
store the lastModified dates

```
// use commons-io 
Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(new File("/path/to/files"), null, true);

Map<File, Long> lastModifiedDates = new HashMap<File, Long>(files.size());
for (File file : files) {
    lastModifiedDates.put(file, file.lastModified());
}
```

---

And check for modifications :

```
// inside a loop (probably a TimerTask)

for (Map.Entry<File, Long> entry : lastModifiedDates.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey().lastModified() > entry.getValue()) {
        // do something
    }
}
```